# Python Recursion Double letters

Tags: python, recursion

So what the task is, is that your supposed to write a recursion function that counts the amount of "double" letters in a string, So for example the string "hmmm" would return 1 and the string "hmmmm" would return 2 and that a string "abb" would return 1. My code is here:

```
def num_double_letters(astr):
    if astr == "" or len(astr) == 1:
        return 0
    elif len(astr) == 2:
        if astr[0] == astr[1]:
            return 1 + num_double_letters(astr[1:])
        else: 
            return 0 + num_double_letters(astr[1:])
    elif astr[0] != astr[1]:
        return 0 + num_double_letters(astr[1:])
    elif astr[0] == astr[1] != astr[2]:
        return 1 + num_double_letters(astr[1:])
    elif astr[0] == astr[1] == astr[2]:
        return 0 + num_double_letters(astr[1:])
```

My problem is that a string with 4 same letters = 1 when its supposed to = 2. And also is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've made it a bit complicated for yourself... there's no need to go deeper into the recursion once the length of your string is 2, and you want to advance by 2, not 1 when you find a double to count the way I think you do. Try this:

```
def num_double_letters(astr):
    if astr == "" or len(astr) == 1:
        return 0
    elif len(astr) == 2:
        if astr[0] == astr[1]:
            return 1
        else: 
            return 0
    elif astr[0] != astr[1]:
        return 0 + num_double_letters(astr[1:])
    elif astr[0] == astr[1]:
        return 1 + num_double_letters(astr[2:])

print(num_double_letters('hmm'))
print(num_double_letters('hmmm'))
print(num_double_letters('hmmmm'))
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
```

You might consider the following more Pythonic and concise:

```
def num_double_letters(astr):
    if len(astr) < 2:
        return 0
    if astr[0] == astr[1]:
        return 1 + num_double_letters(astr[2:])
    return num_double_letters(astr[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you sir!! now that i look at yours the [1:] and [2:] makes a lot more sense.